# Problem with my object that does not stop moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a script for moving an object to the position indicated by the mouse click. If I don't choose to click to another location to move towards, I would like to stop my object if it reaches the previously mentioned position. However, the object doesn't stop when reaching the position and it continues moving.
Here is the code I wrote. I would be grateful if somebody knows how to fix this issue.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    private Vector3 targetPos;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool isMoving;
    private Vector2 direction;
    public  float changeDirCooldown;

    private float changeCool;
    private bool canChangeDir;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        changeCool=changeDirCooldown;
        canChangeDir =true;
    }

  
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canChangeDir)
        {
            
            changeDirCooldown = changeCool;
            SetTargetPosition();
        }
            
        if (changeDirCooldown<=0)
        {
            canChangeDir = true;
            
       
        }
        
        else
        {
            changeDirCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
     
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            Move();
            
        }
        if (this.transform.position == this.targetPos)
        {
            
            isMoving = false;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
          
        }
    }

    private void SetTargetPosition()
    {
        targetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        targetPos.z = transform.position.z;
        direction = targetPos - this.transform.position;
        direction = direction.normalized;
        isMoving = true;
    }
    private void Move()
    {
        rb.velocity = direction * moveSpeed;
        canChangeDir = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probabily a problem with float number tolerance. This line

```
this.transform.position == this.targetPos
```

will almost never result to true, so instead you should do something like this:

```
Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.x - this.targetPos.x) < float.Epsilon &&
Mathf.Abs(this.transform.position.y - this.targetPos.y) < float.Epsilon
```